# Как установить gittorrent в дистрибутиве с portage?

Tags: git, github, torrent, gentoo

А то я что-то не нашел ни ebuild-а ни туториалов никаких...

Что такое GitTorrent описано здесь:
2015-05-29, Chris Ball, Announcing GitTorrent: A Decentralized GitHub, http://blog.printf.net/articles/2015/05/29/announcing-gittorrent-a-decentralized-github/

Answer (score 1):

Как и везде - ставите `Git`, ставите `Node`, через `npm` глобально устанавливаете пакет `gittorrent`:

```
emerge git nodejs
npm install -g gittorrent
```

И всё - можно пользоваться, указывая в `git` в качестве протокола `gittorrent`:

```
git clone gittorrent://github.com/someuser/somerepo
```

Comment: ох, прийдётся изучать npm, потому что идеология gentoo - всё из исходников, а какие бинарники мне сторонний менеджер поставит - ещё вопрос. Надеюсь, что там только javascript'ы. Но лучше бы ебилд сделали и без npm обошлись...

Comment: @hse5yzdx, Не обошлось бы. Получился бы ebuild  с зависимостью от `nodejs` и `git` + того же `npm install -g gittorent` в `src_install()`.

Comment: если бы такой билд прошел приёмку, это бы означало, что разработчик билда проверил что npm не ставит и не использует недоверенных бинарников. А так мне надо проверять самому. Да, я знаю, что многие другие билды ставят из бинарников, но в случае наличия билда я могу свалить ответственность на майнтейнеров дистрибутива, а когда ставлю сам руками - не могу. А без npm можно обойтись, сдублировав его действия средствами bash и portage.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, такие пакеты обычно распространяют в пользовательских оверлеях(здравствуй `Layman`, как дополнение к `portage`). В основной репозиторий вообще не просто пропихнуть свой ebuild - программное обеспечение должно быть либо критичным для системы, либо очень популярным. У обсуждаемого же `gittorrent` максимум 200 активных пользователей по всему миру